# Best way to draw a circle in swift sprite kit without using SKShapeNode (IOS 7 Compatible)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

What is the best way to draw a circle in swift sprite kit **WITHOUT** using [SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/)? The issue is that SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100) does not seem to work with iOS 7.

Here is the iOS 7.1 error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
```

Functionality needed:

- The circle needs to be used like a sprite
- The circle also needs to be used as mask for [SKCropNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html)
- Ability to resize / scale circle using [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: can you show the line of code that generates the error?

Comment: Debugger is showing `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` and not giving proper ref back to any of my written code. I think however that it is this here: `SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKShapeNode/shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:) circleOfRadius it is only Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
But you can use SKShapeNode (Available in iOS 7.0 and later) and set a UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:) to the [path](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/path) property (Available in iOS 7.0 and later) as follow:

```
let myShape = SKShapeNode()
myShape.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)).CGPath
myShape.position = CGPointMake(view.scene!.frame.midX-50, view.scene!.frame.midY-50)
myShape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
myShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
myShape.lineWidth = 10
self.addChild(myShape)
```